# Mongoose: insert object into a sub-document array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to insert a time object into the times array for a specific activity name for a specific user. For example, if the user was "someuser" and I wanted to add a time to the times for guitar I am unsure as to what to do.

```
{
  username: "someuser",
  activities: [
    {
      name: "guitar",
      times: []
    },
    {
      name: "code",
      times: []
    }
  ]
}, {
  username: "anotheruser",
  activities: []
}
```

This is currently the function that I have, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
function appendActivityTime(user, activityName, newRange) {
  User.updateOne(
    {username: user, 'activities.name': activityName},
    { $push: {'activities.$.times': {newRange}},
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully added time range: " + newRange);
        }
    }}
  );
}

appendActivityTime("someuser", "guitar", rangeObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

i've tried your attempt and it worked for me:

```
db.getCollection("test").updateOne(
  { username: "someuser", "activities.name": "guitar" },
  { $push: { "activities.$.times": { from: ISODate(), to: ISODate() } } } //Don't worry about ISODate() in node.js use date objects
)
```

results:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6c384af49dcd4019982b2c"), 
    "username" : "someuser", 
    "activities" : [
        {
            "name" : "guitar", 
            "times" : [
                {
                    "from" : ISODate("2020-09-24T06:15:03.578+0000"), 
                    "to" : ISODate("2020-09-24T06:15:03.578+0000")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "code", 
            "times" : [

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

what i would suggest you using instead is [arrayFilter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), they are much more precise and when you get used to them, they became very handy

Answer (score 0):

If you are not confident with updating nested documents, let mongoose make the query.

let document = await Model.findOne ({ });

document.activities = new_object;

await document.save();